# MS Ops Manager 2012 able to manage remote computer?

Tags: scom

Is it possible to use MS Ops Manager 2012 RC or 2007 to manage remote servers that are not joined via VPN or domain?  I want to use it to manage some AppServers that are off-site.  These app servers do not have their own Active Directory and are not networked together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching the solution seems to be setting up a gateway server for SCOM 2012 that will accept untrusted domains.

http://kevingreeneitblog.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-public-certificates-with-scom_21.html

Answer (score 1):

You are better off looking at sccm rather than scom for remote management.

Comment: even for when it comes to things like monitoring disk space and event logs?  From what I had understood SCCM was best suited for managing apps and deployments.  I'm new to being a MS Admin and previously just used Nagios so i dunno!

Comment: SCCM is the only one that has it's own remote console.  You can take actions on server with SCOM but they need to have teh ability to communicate to the SCOM servers (and at that point you'd just remote desktop).  I'm not sure if even SCCM will work right without at least directaccess (instead of VPN) set up.